# evaluate function in column with cell relative reference vba

Tags: vba, if-statement, range, evaluate

I need to write in column 24 the result of an IF formula that includes reference to relative cell. I think the fatest way is using Evluate function, but I didn't understand how to write each cell relative reference in the formula.
This is my code

```
Set Rng1 = Sheets("Leaders").Cells(12, 19)

g = Evaluate("IF(OR(" & Rng1.Offset(, -3).Address(False, False) & "=""x""," & Rng1.Offset(, -5).Address(False, False) & "=""1:1 matching"")," & Rng1.Offset(, 3).Address(False, False) & "*" & Rng1.Offset(, 4).Address(False, False) & ")")


Sheets("Leaders").Range(Cells(12, 24), Cells(lastRow1, 24)) = Evaluate(g)
```

the result is zero in all cell of column 24

Comment: you already evaluated it, why the `= Evaluate(g)`?  It probably should be just `= g`

Comment: yes, sorry, typo; the right code is  `Sheets("Leaders").Range(Cells(12, 24), Cells(lastRow1, 24)) = g`

Comment: using the evaluate method you will need to loop the rows.  or you could just create the first string as you have it and put the whole in as a formula to all the cells as one.

Comment: but this works without loop `c = Evaluate("INDEX($AA$12:$CD$3207,0,MATCH(" & Rng.Address(False, False) & ",$AA$10:$CD$10,0)+7)")`

Comment: That is because that formula returns an array. the one you are using does not return an array but a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
Sheets("Leaders").Range(Cells(12, 24), Cells(lastRow1, 24)) = "=IF(OR(RC[-8]=""x"",RC[-10]=""1:1 matching""),RC[-2]*RC[-1])"
```